# How to extract part of a string in c++

Tags: c++, c++builder

To Extract part of a string in a given line:

Given line is:

```
D:\AB554P_Itr23\ModelDir\AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat Read 3/18/2010
```

I need to extract only the file name `AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat`. I am using CodeGear RAD Studio C++ Builder. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RTL function [`ExtractFileName()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ExtractFileName) will extract the file name from a path.

Exactly how to split the 3 fields in your example depends very much on what the rules are for forming that line of text. How is it delimited? Is is delimited by spaces? If so, how do you escape spaces in the file path? Until you specify that information, that part of your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @ David: I tried using ExtractFileName() function and it worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: `ExtractFileName()` returns everything that follows the last path delimiter in the input string. If you pass the entire line `"D:\AB554P_Itr23\ModelDir\AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat Read 3/18/2010"` as input, the returned name would be `"AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat Read 3/18/2010"`. You would have to truncate the line to just `"D:\AB554P_Itr23\ModelDir\AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat"` in order for `ExtractFileName()` to return just `"AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat"`.

Answer (score 4):

Did you look into [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

Comment: @ Acme:Thank you. I had already tried using SubString, it worked for one particular file name and path. When I tried with a different file path format, the output obtained was not what I wanted.

Comment: I'm curious as to the many up votes to this answer. It refers to the `substr` function of the STL string, and given the string is a STL string, it could be used in solving the problem. But since the question is tagged *C++Builder* I'll assume the string is a VCL string, and therefore it would be more appropriate to refer to the [`SubString`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString__SubString.html) function of the VCL string classes, and possibly `PosEx` and other function useful in solving the problem.

Answer (score 4):

How about [Boost::Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)...

```
string name = path( "D:\\AB554P_Itr23\\ModelDir\\AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat").filename()
```

Comment: This is not the right answer for C++ Builder which shares an RTL with Delphi and so comes ready equipped with the `ExtractFileName()` function. It's a good answer for different C++ systems I am sure.

Comment: @david This is a good answer, as boost comes with C++ Builder as of 2010. This is as valid as the RTL answer.

Comment: This is certainly valid, however the boost functions do not accept the VCL String classes as parameters, and you would therefore have to call the `c_str` function on them. I'd still say the easiest to do, is used `ExtractFileName` as pointed out by David. But this answer is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle Windows paths, use the [Windows API path functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), such as [`PathFindFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @David: re "What is this 260 character limitation?", see ["Maximum path length limitation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath) in Microsoft's documentation. My source for the lack of checking in `PathFindFileName` is the user's comment at the end of that function's documentation.

Comment: I deleted my side of this discussion, I don't think it added anything of value

Answer (score 1):

1. Here [C++ Parse Split Delimited String](http://www.blog.highub.com/c-plus-plus/c-parse-split-delimited-string/) you get the main function.
2. To delete part after space, use:

string s = "D:\AB554P_Itr23\ModelDir\AB554P_approximation_NodeData.dat Read 3/18/2010";

size_t pos;
pos = s.find(" ");
s.erase(pos);

Now call `split` for '\' to split the remaining part.

Comment: That logic would break if the path contains spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate a regular expression library, such as [Boost Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).